# how to save a tree as the active username using a pipe

Tags: variables, cmd

I am currently trying to make a file that will run a tree command that saves the file as the name of the active user. %userprofile% has C:\ in it and wont work. how do i set %user% to be the name of the user? if this is impossible, then is there a way i can save it as the output of a hostname command?

```
    @echo off
    cd %userprofile%
    tree /a /f > "J:\folder1\%user%"
    Attrib +H +S "J:\folder1\%user%"
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `%user` with `%USERNAME%`:

```
@echo off
cd %userprofile%
tree /a /f > "J:\folder1\%USERNAME%"
Attrib +H +S "J:\folder1\%USERNAME%"
```

Also, I suggest you look into the `set` command. If you run it without any parameters it will show you all the available environment variables.